# Can't post answer using HTML <pre> because it gets misinterpreted as code

Tags: bug, editor, design

I'm trying to answer [Compute rotation matrix using the magnetic field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698092/compute-rotation-matrix-using-the-magnetic-field) and my answer needs to use HTML because I need to show a table containing mathematics formulas. I've posted my answer here, however stackoverflow.com won't let me post it because it says that it's badly formatted code.

---

For Android I think the 3x3 rotation matrix is actually given by:

```
     (cosφ cosψ - sinφ sinψ sinθ)     sinφ cosθ     ( cosφ sinψ + sinφ cosψ sinθ)
    -(sinφ cosψ + cosφ sinψ sinθ)     cosφ cosθ     (-sinφ sinψ + cosφ cosψ sinθ)
              -sinψ cosθ                 -sinθ                  cosφ cosθ
```

where

```
    φ = azimuth
    θ = pitch
    ψ = roll
```

which corresponds to the 3x3 Android rotation matrix R[0] to R[8] via

```
    R[0] R[1] R[2]
    R[3] R[4] R[5]
    R[6] R[7] R[8]
```

Can this be fixed, is there a work-around?

Update 28-Mar-2013.  I've attached an image to show the problem I encounter, because someone said that they don't get the problem when they try and post.  If some people don't have the problem, is it because they have different rights/reputation etc compared to me?

[image]

Update2 28-Mar-2013: I typed in just a few lines (see below) and reproduced the problem (see image).  I didn't enter any tabs.  However, it took several minutes for the red box to come up telling me that my post appeared to contain code that's not properly formatted.

---

line before blank line

```
    r[0]
```

line after blank line

---

[image]

Update 3-Apr-2013: Today I was able to post the answer :-).  Either there's been a fix released to stackoverflow.com, or it's because I've now got a higher reputation there and (as discussed in the comments below), the checks made probably vary depending on reputation.

Comment: Note: This user entered this report at my request, after trying to help them work around it several times.

Comment: I've [copy/pasted the above on SO without any problem](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10698354/2). @TimPost can you repro?

Comment: I've updated the query to show the problem occurring!  Is it possible that people with different rights/reputation don't encounter the problem?

Comment: @PaulDoust: Are there tabs in your paste?

Comment: @Sklivvz - Same, didn't reproduce. Something must be subtly different about what was posted here and what he's posting on SO? I can't trigger the same error he's getting.

Comment: @0A0D: no tabs.  Also, I've just updated the question to show that I can reproduce the problem with a very small draft post.  In case it helps, I'm running windows 7 professional (64 bit), and I get the problem with both Chrome and Internet explorer version 10.

Comment: @Stochastically: I can't reproduce your issue in the latest screenshot. I created an answer just like you did. Maybe there is a different filter because you are not a 10K+ user like me?

Comment: @0A0D, yes that's my best guess too.  But even so, it's still a bug isn't it?  Surely everything between <pre> and </pre> should be excluded from any formatted code checking, regardless of my reputation?

Comment: @Stochastically: Not sure why you are using the <pre> tags?

Comment: I wanted to do a table but that's not allowed, and the recommendation (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites ) was to use <pre>.  Also, I need html so that I can use greek letters via &#966 etc!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to using HTML is using [Roger's Online Equation Editor](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/index.php) that will return an image that you can insert into your question or answer (using LaTeX of course). Or you can try [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful :-).